# What is the best resizable byte buffer available in Java?

Tags: java

I need a byte buffer class in Java for single-threaded use. The buffer should resize when it's full, rather than throw an exception or something. Very important issue for me is performance.

What would you recommend?

ADDED:
At the momement I use ByteBuffer but it cannot resize. I need one that can resize.

Comment: Side note: Microbenchmarking and notes on byte buffers: http://www.evanjones.ca/software/java-bytebuffers.html

Comment: how do you put performance and single-threaded use together, a normal byte[] tops anything easily.

Comment: cannot use byte[] because I don't know the length of the data I have to write.

Comment: sure you can, just need to enlarge, if need be :). but then you can wrap a ByteBuffer easily. What I personally use is a subclass of ByteArrayOutputStream (buf and count are protected) and when I am done I can wrap the byte[] into a ByteBuffer, smth like wrap(buf, 0, count)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any reason not to use the boring normal [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)?

As mentioned by miku above, [Evan Jones gives a review of different types](http://www.evanjones.ca/software/java-bytebuffers.html) and shows that it is very application dependent. So without knowing further details it is hard to speculate.

I would start with ByteArrayOutputStream, and only if profiling shows it is your performance bottleneck move to something else. Often when you believe the buffer code is the bottleneck, it will actually be network or other IO - wait until profiling shows you need an optimisation before wasting time finding a replacement.

If you are moving to something else, then other factors you will need to think about:

- You have said you are using single threaded use, so BAOS's synchronization is not needed
- what is the buffer being filled by and fed into? If either end is already wired to use Java NIO, then using a direct [ByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) is very efficient.
- Are you using a circular buffer or a plain linear buffer? If you are then the [Ostermiller Utils](http://ostermiller.org/utils/) are pretty efficient, and GPL'd

Comment: @MinimeDJ - I'm not sure what you are doing, but "could be some performance impact" is a long way from "there is a performance problem".

Comment: Nick Fortescue, vote up for your great answer. I am serializing object to store them in NOSQL DB. At the moment I use ByteBuffer. Will try BAOS to see how it performs.

Comment: @MinimeDJ, biased lock (synchrnized java keyword) costs one CAS 1st time and then compare/jump (1-3 CPU cycles or so), it's practically free for single thread use.

Comment: @Nick, how do you profile that the ByteArrayOutputStream is the bottleneck. It can't be done through a normal profiler. Since the code path is just tiny and it's not guaranteed to have a 'safe point' there. If enhanced and peppered w/ counters (yada, yada) then the optimizations would not be the same. Micro-profiling is quite hard to get it right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a direct ByteBuffer.  Direct memory uses virtual memory to start with is only allocated to the application when it is used. i.e. the amount of main memory it uses re-sizes automagically.

Create a direct ByteBuffer larger than you need and it will only consume what you use.

Comment: nice one, automagically for page faults :D but the amount of the direct memory is limited (sure it can be set high enough, though). DirectByteBuffers need to be pooled since they are quite expensive to allocated and especially to de-allocated.

Answer (score 2):

you can also write manual code for checking the buffer content continously and if its full then make a new buffer of greater size and shift all the data in that new buffer.